# elasticsearch sort data in fuzzy mode

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

### I want to sort data by more similar in elasticsearch with fuzzy mode

we have to record 
1.panadol
2.penadol

when I search with panadol or penadol the first result is (penadol) but I want wen I type (panadol) the first result appear (panadol) and the second result id (penadol) etc ..

```
$params = [
'index' => 'my_index',
'type' => 'my_type',
'body' => [
    "track_scores"=> true,
    'sort'=>[
        'name'=> ['reverse'=>true],
        '_score'=> ['order'=>'desc'],
    ],
    'query' => [

        'fuzzy' => [
            'name' => [
                "value"=> 'panadol',
                "fuzziness" =>     2,

            ]
        ]

    ],


]
```

];

Answer (score 2):

Fuzziness is not meant for scoring. You can find more info about it [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html).

If you want to sort the results by relevance to the original phrase your searched for you can use either the [phrase-suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) or the [completion-suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html), depending on your needs (and your data).